# Is this define_method use case too complex?

Tags: ruby, oop, metaprogramming

I've been bashing my head against this for about three days now. I've created a class that models html pages and tells cucumber step definitions where to populate form data:

```
class FlightSearchPage

  def initialize(browser, page, brand)
    @browser = browser
    @start_url = page

    #Get reference to config file
    config_file = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', 'config', 'site_config.yml')

    #Store hash of config values in local variable
    config = YAML.load_file config_file

    @brand = brand #brand is specified by the customer in the features file

    #Define instance variables from the hash keys
    config.each do |k,v|
      instance_variable_set("@#{k}",v)
    end
  end

  def method_missing(sym, *args, &block)
    @browser.send sym, *args, &block
  end

  def page_title
    #Returns contents of <title> tag in current page.
    @browser.title
  end

  def visit
    @browser.goto(@start_url)
  end

  def set_origin(origin)
    self.text_field(@route[:attribute] => @route[:origin]).set origin
  end

  def set_destination(destination)
    self.text_field(@route[:attribute] => @route[:destination]).set destination
  end

  def set_departure_date(outbound)
    self.text_field(@route[:attribute]  => @date[:outgoing_date]).set outbound
  end

  # [...snip]

end
```

As you can see, I've used instance_variable_set to create the variables that hold the references on the fly, and the variable names and values are supplied by the config file (which is designed to be editable by people who aren't necessarily familiar with Ruby).

Unfortunately, this is a big, hairy class and I'm going to have to edit the source code every time I want to add a new field, which is obviously bad design so I've been trying to go a stage further and create the methods that set the variable names dynamically with define_method and this is what's kept me awake until 4am for the last few nights.

This is what I've done:

```
require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/flight_search_page')

class SetFieldsByType <  FlightSearchPage
  def text_field(config_hash)
    define_method(config_hash) do |data|
      self.text_field(config_hash[:attribute] => config_hash[:origin]).set data
    end
  end
end
```

The idea is that all you need to do to add a new field is add a new entry to the YAML file and define_method will create the method to allow cucumber to populate it.

At the moment, I'm having problems with scope - Ruby thinks that define_method is a member of @browser. But what I want to know is: is this even feasible? Have I totally misunderstood  define_method?

Comment: I'm not totally sure I understand, but: wouldn't you want to read the config file on class load and add class-level methods then?

Comment: That you don't understand is an indication to me that what I'm trying to do is a bit strange. Do you mean that you'd expect to see the requires and file loads outside the class definition? As you can see, I'm a novice - I'm really a tester, not a developer

Comment: (Moving comments to answer for space reasons, but it's *not* an answer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an appropriate case for metaprogramming, but it looks like you're going about it the wrong way.

First of all, is there going to be a different config file for each *instance* of FlightSearchPage or just one config file that controls all pages? It looks like you're loading the same config file regardless of the arguments to `initialize` so I'm guessing your case is the former.

If that is so, you need to move all of your metaprogramming code into the class (outside method definitions). I.e. when the class is defined, you want it to load the config file and then each instance is created based on that config. Right now you have it reloading the config file every time you create an instance, which seems incorrect. For example, `define_method` belongs to `Module` so it should appear in class scope, rather than in an instance method.

On the other hand, if you do want a different config for each instance, you need to move all of your metaprogramming code into the singleton class e.g. `define_singleton_method` rather than `define_method`.

Comment: Thanks Max. It also seems that you've nailed my scope question. The idea is that the config file is edited with the appropriate values for each implementation of the test framework, so yes, the former. And I strongly suspected that I was going about it the wrong way. I'm very new to metaprogramming. Thanks again.

Comment: Another question - if I load the config file in the class, do I need to use class variables?

Comment: If you're using metaprogramming, you shouldn't need class variables at all: the information from the config file will be "stored" in the structure of the class you create from it (e.g. the instance methods defined at runtime). On the other hand you could probably avoid metaprogramming entirely by storing the config file info in a class variable. It all depends on what you think makes the class easiest to work with.

Comment: It's less about ease of use and more about flexibility - I want to be able to create methods from hash keys (from the YAML file) and deriving arguments from the hash values. This gives people without Ruby skills the ability to configure the Page object, and eliminates the need to change the class source code. If I put the methods in a class variable, I'd have to open up the class definition and edit the source every time I needed to add or modify an existing field.

Answer (score 2):

> Do you mean that you'd expect to see the requires and file loads outside the class definition?

No, inside the class definition. Ruby class declarations are just code that execute in the order it's seen. Things like `attr_accessor` are just class methods that happen to do things to the class being defined, *as it's being defined*. This *seems* like what you want to do.

In your case you'd read the YAML file instead, and run your own logic to create accessors, build any backing data required, etc. I don't totally grok the usecase, but it doesn't sound unusual or difficult--yet.

That said, how much "convenience" do you get by putting these definitions in a YAML file? Consider something like I did once to create page instances I used to drive Watir:

```
class SomePage < HeavyWatir
  has_text :fname     # Assumed default CSS accessor pattern
  has_text :whatever, accessor: 'some accessor mechanism', option: 'some other option'
end
```

The `has_xxx` were class methods that created instance variable accessors (just like `attr_accessor` does), built up some other data structures I used to make sure all the things that were supposed to be on the page actually were, and so on. For example, *very* roughly:

```
page = SomePage.new
page.visit
if page.missing_fields?
  # Do something saying the page isn't complete
end
```

It *sounds* like you want something vaguely similar: you have a bunch of "things" you want to give to the class (or a sub-class, or you could mix it in to an arbitrary class, etc.)

Those "things" have additional functionality, that functionality works in multiple ways, like:

**Things-that-happen-during-definition**

E.g., `has_text` adds the name to a class instance hash ofthe page's metadata, like field names.

**Things-that-happen-during-usage**

E.g., when `fname=` is called set a flag in the instance's metadata saying the setter was called.

Comment: Ok, I'll need a little time to absorb this. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: I think that what I'm trying to do is different. The instance methods (set_xxx) identify a particular html form element and set the element with the value of the argument passed in. So, for instance, it could set an element with id of 'departure_port' with the value 'EDI'. This would imply something like set_origin('EDI'), which would set the physical text field in the browser with the value 'EDI'

Comment: @Rogue_Leader I don't see how it's different at a conceptual level. The setter uses metadata about the field (like a selector) to access the page. What's the difference? You don't even need "set_xxx", you can just use "xxx="

Comment: "You don't even need "set_xxx", you can just use "xxx=" " - Oh, of course!